# What is the purpose of the beginner tutorials? I'm following them but I'm not sure what I am doing or why

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin

This is where I am and I am sort of familiar with linux, I managed to install a few different distros to this machine. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial), Kinetic Kame ROS, and trying to get Gazebo working.

Its just not clear to me why I have to do all of this... I'd like to jump right into building robotics simulations.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331534/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-beginner-tutorials?-i%27m-following-them-but-i%27m-not-sure-what-i-am-doing-or-why./) by [Underdog](https://answers.ros.org/users/45150/underdog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:
Observation: you've tagged this `ros2` and `xenial`, but then link to the Catkin tutorials, which are ROS 1 only.

Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics, Services, Parameters, and catkin (the build system) are all prerequisites for building and controlling ROS robots.

If you want a better overview of how all of these things are used in a robotics simulation environment, take a look at the turtlesim tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials

If you specifically want to use gazebo, you may also want to look at the gazebo tutorials: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm a beginner, too in ROS! And the life is not that easy with it, but for sure without it much code I've had to do.

For the moment I do some paid classes at robotignite and build real robot using ros. After many tutorials, the hands on approach plus the classes gave me the biggest gain with ROS.

Watch this guy, it has some insights about the course and his notes are my god veeery neat :)
https://github.com/eborghi10/ROS-in-Five-Days

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) with karma: 112 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) on 2019-08-26**:
Robotignite is the best practical resource for getting familiar with ROS. All of the simulations and packages are set up for you. I did the Udacity Nanodegree too, but expensive for similar coverage of topics.